# No log file error in Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, logging, config

I'm trying to use a piece of software (Quillpad) which won't compile due to:

```
File "startquill_cherry.py", line 31, in <module>
    logging.config.fileConfig('logsystem.conf')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 85, in fileConfig
    handlers = _install_handlers(cp, formatters)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 163, in _install_handlers
    h = klass(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 913, in __init__
    StreamHandler.__init__(self, self._open())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 943, in _open
    stream = open(self.baseFilename, self.mode)

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'mydir/logs/root.log'
```

This error is triggered by the following code in the startquill_cherry.py file:

```
logging.config.fileConfig('logsystem.conf')
logger = logging.getLogger('quillpad')
```

The relevant code in logsystem.conf (I think) is the following:

```
[loggers]
keys=root,datacollector,mailcollector

[logger_root]
level=INFO
handlers=default

[handler_default]
class=FileHandler
level=INFO
formatter=default
args=('logs/quill.log', 'a')
```

Any thoughts on this? I don't really understand how the config files in Python 2.7 work here.  I was able to make the program compile by commenting out the Python code, but eventually it causes another error.